# Can't access memory cache - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to store my data in memory cache and access it from another controller ,what i have done is

```
 MemoryCache myCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
 //responseQID is my data i have already seen it contains data 
 myCache.Set("QIDresponse", responseQID);
```

in another controller i want to get this data :

```
 MemoryCache myCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
       var inmemory= myCache.Get("QIDresponse");
```

inmemory is null, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You created two separate caches. They won't share any data, because they're separate. Use the same `MemoryCache` instance in both constructors.

Comment: @canton7 i would appreacite if you tell me how

Comment: Create the `MemoryCache` once, and make sure both of your controllers can access that same reference. Alternatively, use `MemoryCache.Default`

Comment: Or inject memory cache via [DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.memorycacheservicecollectionextensions.addmemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and resolve it in controllers.

Comment: @canton7 i dont have access to Default

Comment: It's a static property on `MemoryCache`, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.default?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common memory cache is provided by ASP.NET Core. You just need to inject it into each controller or other service where you want to access it. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

You need to ensure memory caching is registered, note this from the docs:

> For most apps, IMemoryCache is enabled. For example, calling AddMvc,
> AddControllersWithViews, AddRazorPages,
> AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine, and many other Add{Service} methods
> in ConfigureServices, enables IMemoryCache. For apps that are not
> calling one of the preceding Add{Service} methods, it may be necessary
> to call AddMemoryCache in ConfigureServices.

To ensure this is the case, you add the registration within Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();

...
```

Once memory caching is registered in Startup.cs, you can inject into any controller like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

...
```

Then use this `_cache` instance rather than using `new` to create one.